# Структура на этапе компилияции (не времени исполнения)

Tags: c

Мне бы хотелось получить доступ к структуре на этапе компиляции (а не времени исполнения) с помощью макроса. Например, у меня есть набор команд, и каждая имеет свой шестнадцатеричный код и длину ответа.
Итак, мне нужно получить одно из этих значений через единое имя команды.

Скажем, команда называется `READ_SOMETHING_FROM_THAT_PLACE` и имеет код `0xAB`, и 7 байт ответа.

Это попытка **избежать следующих двух определений**:

```
#define READ_SOMETHING_FROM_THAT_PLACE_CODE 0xAB
#define READ_SOMETHING_FROM_THAT_PLACE_LEN 7
```

Вместо этого было бы более удобно и надёжно иметь доступ через одно вхождение. Я предполагаю что это могло бы выглядеть как:

`CODE(READ_SOMETHING_FROM_THAT_PLACE)` и препроцессор вернул бы `0xAB`

`LEN(READ_SOMETHING_FROM_THAT_PLACE)` и препроцессор вернул бы `7`.

Это вообще возможно? Как это можно сделать?

Comment: В чем разница между записью `READ_SOMETHING_FROM_THAT_PLACE_CODE` и `CODE(READ_SOMETHING_FROM_THAT_PLACE)` препроцесор в обоих случаях вернет `0xAB`  Что вы хотите улучшить ?

Comment: @Yaroslav, хочет избавиться от первых двух определений. Чтобы было что-то вроде `#def SMTH(key) {len: 15, code: 0xab}[key]`. Но compile-time.

Comment: @vp_arth от этих двух определений все равно неизбавится можно только объединить при создании например `#define CREAT(name,vlen,vcode)   struct command name={.len=vlen,.code=vocode}`

Comment: На c++11 и шаблонах - можно, и очень даже легко, если не гнушаетесь.

Comment: @gbg интересно взглянуть, можете написать в ответ?

Comment: А где вы предлагаете хранить значения для препроцессора? Для обычного Си это делается на раз-два-три! При этом всё те же константы. Компилятор при включенной оптимизации сам подставит куда нужно как удобнее и быстрее.

Comment: @0andriy это и был мой вопрос, что и где хранить, вам вопрос понятен? Мне ваш не совсем, простите.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov, мой вопрос на то, чтобы вы домашнее задание сделали. Когда на него ответите, ответите и на свой.

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать [конкатенацию](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation)(`##`):

```
#define PREFIX_CODE 15
#define GET(a) PREFIX_ ## a

GET(CODE); // 15
```

Или наоборот:

```
#define READ_SOMETHING_FROM_THAT_PLACE_CODE 0xAB
#define READ_SOMETHING_FROM_THAT_PLACE_LEN 7

#define GETCODE(prefix) prefix ## _CODE
#define GETLEN(prefix) prefix ## _LEN

GETCODE(READ_SOMETHING_FROM_THAT_PLACE); // 0xAB
GETLEN(READ_SOMETHING_FROM_THAT_PLACE); // 7
```

Comment: А можно на примере приведённых мной обозначений двух параметров Код и Длина?

Comment: Погодите, видимо я неверно понял. Я решил, что нужен сокращённый доступ к тем двум константам)

Comment: Да, нужен доступ к двум константам через одно имя. И кстати, таких пар может быть набор.

Comment: спасибо, но не очень нравится два различных имя в первых двух определениях, можно ли ограничиться одним и макросоами?

Comment: Макросы - это таки инструмент замены/подстановок. Не уверен, что получится без рантайма, хотя давайте подождём более опытных товарищей.